# Confusion about one example to check if an object is an iterator in Python

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

I have read some posts on stackoverflow about how to check an object is an iterator in Python but it seems that they did not solve my question. I have this example from the book *Effective Python*

```
def normalize_defensive(numbers):
   if iter(numbers) is iter(numbers):  # An iterator — bad!
       raise TypeError(‘Must supply a container’)
   total = sum(numbers)
   result = []
   for value in numbers:
       percent = 100 * value / total
       result.append(percent)
   return result
```

To use:

```
visits = [15, 35, 80]
normalize_defensive(visits)  # No error
visits = ReadVisits(path)  # ReadVisits is a class with an __iter__ method.
normalize_defensive(visits)  # No error
it = iter(visits)
normalize_defensive(it)
>>>
TypeError: Must supply a container
```

So my question is in this line:

```
if iter(numbers) is iter(numbers):  # An iterator — bad!
```

Why this line check if the variable numbers is an iterator? When visits = [15, 35, 80], should it be true that `iter(numbers) is iter(numbers)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call an *iterable*, calling `iter()` on such an object will always produce a *new* iterator object. But calling `iter()` on an *iterator* will always return the same object; it is a requirement of the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) that they do.

From the [`iterator.__iter__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__iter__):

> Return the iterator object itself. This is required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the `for` and `in` statements.

Because `iter(iterable)` always returns *itself*, the test `iter(obj) is iter(obj)` will be true; the same object is returned in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand Martijn's explanation, take a look at the following:

```
>>> numbers = [15, 35, 80]
>>> it  = iter(numbers)
>>> it2 = iter(numbers)
>>> it3 = iter(it)
>>> id(it1)
51123792
>>> id(it2)
51056464    # id of it2 is different from it1
>>> id(it3) 
51123792    # iterator of iterator it3 has the same id as iterator it1
```

So if `numbers` was an `iterator`, calling `iter` on `numbers` will always return objects that are internally identical: `iter(numbers) is iter(numbers)` will be `True`.